How to batch in SQL for set of records from table
Hi The table details looks like :
Table name: TBL_TXN

My query output should be like this :
While fetching the data we need to batch based on limits. so the limit is each batch should have max of 2 transaction and max item count should be 4.

Thanks for the help !!

This kind of problem requires either looping or recursion. You should be more specific about which database platform you have.

I have Oracle data base and trying to achieve this without looping

Do the batches need to have the same participant?

yes batches need to have same participant.

From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT transaction, participant, item_count, batch_id
FROM   (
         SELECT transaction, participant, item_count,
                TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(transaction, 4)) AS trans_id
         FROM   table_name
       )
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         ORDER BY trans_id
         MEASURES
           MATCH_NUMBER() AS batch_id
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN ( first_trans transaction_limit{0,1} )
         DEFINE
           transaction_limit AS  SUM(item_count) <= 4
                              AND participant = FIRST(participant)
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (transaction, participant, item_count) AS
  SELECT 'TSN1', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN2', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN3', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN4', 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN5', 1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN6', 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN7', 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN8', 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN9', 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN10', 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN11', 2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN12', 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN13', 3, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TSN14', 3, 1 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



TRANSACTION
PARTICIPANT
ITEM_COUNT
BATCH_ID




TSN1
1
2
1


TSN2
1
2
1


TSN3
1
2
2


TSN4
1
3
3


TSN5
1
4
4


TSN6
2
2
5


TSN7
2
4
6


TSN8
2
3
7


TSN9
2
2
8


TSN10
2
2
8


TSN11
2
2
9


TSN12
3
2
10


TSN13
3
1
10


TSN14
3
1
11



fiddle

This worked perfectly thanks

Just be careful that "first_trans" pattern will match everything that is no a "transaction_limit", in other words if you have out of range "item count" (e.g. 5) they will be assigned a batch id... you may solve it by defining first_trans as    "first_trans AS item_count BETWEEN 1 AND 4"

This needs recursive query to get the desired output.
Here is a way to get the output you desire. The way to understand is to run each of the blocks separately to get the intermediate results and corelate with the intension.
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'TSN1' as trans,1 participant,2 item_cnt from dual union all
  SELECT 'TSN2',1,2 from dual union all
  SELECT 'TSN3',1,2 from dual union all
  SELECT 'TSN4',1,3 from dual union all
  SELECT 'TSN5',1,4 from dual union all
  SELECT 'TSN6',2,2 from dual union all
  SELECT 'TSN7',2,4 from dual union all
  SELECT 'TSN8',2,3 from dual union all
  SELECT 'TSN9',2,2 from dual union all
  SELECT 'TSN10',2,2 from dual
)
,ranking_tran 
as (select row_number() over(order by cast(replace(trans,'TSN','') as number))  as rnk
           ,trans
           ,participant
           ,item_cnt
     from data
    )
,cte(rnk,trans,participant,orig_item_cnt,item_cnt,trans_cnt,batchid)
  as (select rnk
             ,trans
             ,participant
             ,item_cnt as orig_item_cnt
             ,item_cnt             
             ,1 as trans_cnt
             ,1 as batchid
        from ranking_tran
       where rnk=1
    union all
    select d.rnk
          ,d.trans
          ,d.participant
          ,d.item_cnt as orig_Item_cnt
          ,case when c.item_cnt+ d.item_cnt>4 then d.item_cnt else c.item_cnt+d.item_cnt end
          ,case when c.trans_cnt +1 =3 then 1 else c.trans_cnt + 1 end
          ,case when c.item_cnt+ d.item_cnt>4 
                  or (c.trans_cnt +1=4) then
                   c.batchid +1
                else c.batchid
           end
      from cte c
      join ranking_tran d
        on c.rnk+1=d.rnk
      )
select trans,participant,orig_Item_cnt,batchid 
  from cte

--db fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/82-hVTbg
+-------+-------------+---------------+---------+
| TRANS | PARTICIPANT | ORIG_ITEM_CNT | BATCHID |
+-------+-------------+---------------+---------+
| TSN1  |           1 |             2 |       1 |
| TSN2  |           1 |             2 |       1 |
| TSN3  |           1 |             2 |       2 |
| TSN4  |           1 |             3 |       3 |
| TSN5  |           1 |             4 |       4 |
| TSN6  |           2 |             2 |       5 |
| TSN7  |           2 |             4 |       6 |
| TSN8  |           2 |             3 |       7 |
| TSN9  |           2 |             2 |       8 |
| TSN10 |           2 |             2 |       8 |
+-------+-------------+---------------+---------+


The OP clarified in comments that "batches need to have same participant". You would need to add that behaviour to your CASE expressions because currently it will put multiple participants into a batch fiddle.
